# R function rolling division

Tags: r

I can perform a rolling division on vectors, i can take my data, then lag the same data and perform the division:

```
# Dummy Data
sample <- c(4,5,6,7,8,4,2,6,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6)
lagSam <- lag(sample) # Lag by 1
output <- sample / lagSam # Perform division
sample.df <- data.frame(sample, desired = output)

with the desired output: 
   sample   desired
1       4        NA
2       5 1.2500000
3       6 1.2000000
4       7 1.1666667
5       8 1.1428571
6       4 0.5000000
7       2 0.5000000
8       6 3.0000000
9       5 0.8333333
10      4 0.8000000
11      3 0.7500000
12      2 0.6666667
13      1 0.5000000
14      2 2.0000000
15      3 1.5000000
16      4 1.3333333
17      5 1.2500000
18      6 1.2000000
```

My question is, how do I do the same on a data frame? I have over 100 columns and need to take a rolling division of each. I am trying to write a function and use roll apply:

```
# My attempt 
division <- function(x) {
  #tail(x,1) / head(x,1)
  x / lag(x)
}

rollapplyr(sample.df$sample, 1, division, fill = NA)
```

I tried to lag it with head and tail and then again with x / lag of x.

Both results produce NA's.

Comment: Seems like you have a function, `division`, that you want to apply to all columns of a dataframe? So `lapply(sample.df, division)`? If your `division` function takes care of the *rolling* part by itself, you don't need to double up the roll by using rollapply.

Comment: Or `apply(sample.df, 2, FUN = division)`, no need for an external package.

Comment: @RuiBarradas does that code work on your computer? I get all `1`s (as I would expect, given the way `apply` and family work).

Comment: the division output should look like desired column...

Comment: @r2evans His function `division` is wrong, see the output of `lag(sample)`. I have rewritten it as `division <- function(x) x / c(NA, x[-length(x)])`.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide that as an answer, since without your redefinition of `division` it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I frequently find that I want the `dplyr::lag` behavior but am startled a little when `stats::lag` returns a `tsp`-like object.

You're close with `tail/head` functionality. Using negative `n`:

> ```
>   n: a single integer. If positive, size for the resulting object:
>       number of elements for a vector (including lists), rows for a
>       matrix or data frame or lines for a function. If negative,
>       all but the 'n' last/first number of elements of 'x'.
> ```

```
c(NA, tail(sample.df$sample,n=-1) / head(sample.df$sample,n=-1))
#  [1]        NA 1.2500000 1.2000000 1.1666667 1.1428571 0.5000000 0.5000000
#  [8] 3.0000000 0.8333333 0.8000000 0.7500000 0.6666667 0.5000000 2.0000000
# [15] 1.5000000 1.3333333 1.2500000 1.2000000
```

Note that your thought to do a *rolling* apply is slightly problematic in that it will divide a number by the result of the previous division, not the previous value. That is, `c(2,3,4)` in a rolling divide should start with an initial value (say, `1`, the division-identity), and go with something like `c(2/1, 3/(2/1), 4/(3/(2/1)))`, not what (I think) you requested.

This drives the function to be:

```
division <- function(x) c(NA, tail(x,n=-1) / head(x,n=-1))
```

So then you can do

```
lapply(sample.df, division)
```

If you only want to run this on select columns, I'd do

```
ind <- 1
lapply(sample.df[ind], division)
# $sample
#  [1]        NA 1.2500000 1.2000000 1.1666667 1.1428571 0.5000000 0.5000000
#  [8] 3.0000000 0.8333333 0.8000000 0.7500000 0.6666667 0.5000000 2.0000000
# [15] 1.5000000 1.3333333 1.2500000 1.2000000
cbind(sample.df, lapply(sample.df[ind], division))
#    sample desired    sample
# 1       4       1        NA
# 2       5       1 1.2500000
# 3       6       1 1.2000000
# 4       7       1 1.1666667
# 5       8       1 1.1428571
# 6       4       1 0.5000000
# 7       2       1 0.5000000
# 8       6       1 3.0000000
# 9       5       1 0.8333333
# 10      4       1 0.8000000
# 11      3       1 0.7500000
# 12      2       1 0.6666667
# 13      1       1 0.5000000
# 14      2       1 2.0000000
# 15      3       1 1.5000000
# 16      4       1 1.3333333
# 17      5       1 1.2500000
# 18      6       1 1.2000000
```

This of course generated a duplicate name, but it's a start.

BTW: *rolling* generally has to do with a cumulative process on a vector. What you are looking for is applying one function to each vector individually and capturing the response.

Comment: Ok the desired output works with your code. However, I need to apply this over over 100 columns. Hence the function, if I place that logic in a function it doesnt work again. Can this even be applied in a rolling manner?

Comment: @AndrewBannerman read that last sentence of this answer again. You don't need `rolling` functionality here, since you're just getting `x / lag(x)` for every value. You just need, as you said, to apply this function to all your columns. Try `apply(full.df, 1, division)`.

Comment: understood! that makes sense now as I basically have it with x /  lag(x) like you said! Thanks for the great responses

Comment: @cmaher and AndrewBannerman, it should be noted that the use of `apply(...)` will return a *transposed* matrix, not a `data.frame`, and dimensions likely swapped with what is expected. The use of `lapply` reserves the `list`-like property of `data.frame`s, and can easily be added as columns accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few ways:

**1) diff**

```
transform(sample.df, desired = c(NA, exp(diff(log(sample)))))
##    sample   desired
## 1       4        NA
## 2       5 1.2500000
## 3       6 1.2000000
## 4       7 1.1666667
## 5       8 1.1428571
## ... etc ...
```

To apply this to multiple columns using the built in data frame `anscombe`:

```
rbind(NA, exp(diff(log(as.matrix(anscombe)))))
```

**2) diff.zoo**

```
library(zoo)

z <- zoo(sample.df$sample)
merge(z, desired = diff(z, arith = FALSE), all = TRUE)
##    z   desired
## 1  4        NA
## 2  5 1.2500000
## 3  6 1.2000000
## 4  7 1.1666667
## 5  8 1.1428571
## ... etc ...
```

To apply it to all columns of `anscombe`:

```
z <- zoo(rbind(NA, anscombe))
diff(z, arith = FALSE)
```

**3) dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)

sample.df %>% mutate(desired = sample/lag(sample))
##    sample   desired
## 1       4        NA
## 2       5 1.2500000
## 3       6 1.2000000
## 4       7 1.1666667
## 5       8 1.1428571
## ... etc ...
```

To apply this to all columns of `anscombe`:

```
anscombe %>% mutate_all(funs(. / lag(.)))
```

**4) rollapplyr**

```
library(zoo)

transform(sample.df, desired = rollapplyr(sample, 2, function(x) x[2]/x[1], fill = NA))
##    sample   desired
## 1       4        NA
## 2       5 1.2500000
## 3       6 1.2000000
## 4       7 1.1666667
## 5       8 1.1428571
```

To apply it to all columns of `anscombe`:

```
rollapplyr(anscombe, 2, function(x) x[2]/x[1], fill = NA))
```

**5) lag.ts**

```
transform(sample.df, desired = c(NA, lag(ts(sample)) / ts(sample)))
##    sample   desired
## 1       4        NA
## 2       5 1.2500000
## 3       6 1.2000000
## 4       7 1.1666667
## 5       8 1.1428571
```

To apply it to all columns of `anscombe` use the following. Note that dplyr should NOT be loaded since it annoyingly clobbers `lag` with its own `lag`.  Alternately use `stats::lag`:

```
lag(ts(anscombe)) / ts(anscombe)
```